# Java link in a swt FormText

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am using the `FormText` from `org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.FormText` and I want the user to be able to enter text in the input of the forms `TextForm` but at the same time to have some clickable areas.
For example I have the form with the text:

"If you want to open blabla click **HERE**" and if you click on "**HERE**" then I want to open an `OpenConfirm` from `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.openConfirm`.

I am not even sure if I can do this using `FormText`
I tried to add the "hyperlink" using `StyledText` but didn't work.

Does anyone have another solution? Maybe not exactly with FormText, but with any text box where you could write something. Thank you!

Comment: FormText is read only so the user can't type anywhere in that. I don't think anything really supports having something clickable in the area where the user is typing if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry. And yes, that is what I meant, an area where the user is typing and you can click on something. Thank you for the answer @greg-449 (: